# Connect to SQL Server using PHP in MacOs Sierra : Could not find driver

Tags: php, macos, pdo, macos-sierra

I have an app written in PHP that connects to MySQL. One of my customers want to use SQL Server instead. In the past i had a big headache to make PDO connect to SQL Server in a Windows 2008 machine, but now i'm on a Mac with Sierra. Is there any 'easy' way to configure this connection, without having to download sources, compile and so on ?

By simply using the code below :

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=dbserver.domein.com;Database=testdb", "User@dbserver", "Password");
```

I get the 'Could not find driver' error.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Making a connection with PDO to an SQL Serve shouldn't be a problem.

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=dbserver.domein.com;Database=testdb", "User@dbserver", "Password");
```

However you should check the query's for some DB Server specific query's.
While they are both SQL there are still some differences between the two.

Comment: When i try this way, i get the 'could not find driver.' error

Comment: Which PDO drivers are installed, if `dblib` is one of them you could try using that one.

Comment: I have only mysql, pgsql and sqllite... How to install dblib ?

Comment: Well I haven't tried this myself and you said you do not wish to compile a lot but sadly I only know of this option: https://github.com/BellevueCollege/public-docs/blob/master/PHP/configure-mssql-pdodblib-mac.md

Comment: Thank you but it's really too complicated for me and chances are big i'd end up damaging my development environment...

Comment: Maybe you can convince your customer to run MySQL anyway. Or change the OS from which PHP is being run. If you can run it on a Windows system the `sqlsrv` driver can be easily installed if not already available.